# Transience of random walks starting from each of the sites which have been already visited

Tags: probability, probability-theory, markov-chains, markov-process, random-walk

Consider a simple random walk on $\mathbb{Z}^d$, $d \geq 3$, which starts from the origin. As $d \geq 3$, there is a positive probability that the random walk never visits the origin again.

Now, let a new simple random start from any of the vertices which have been visited by the first random walk. Is the probability that no of the new random walks visits the origin positive as well?

Perhaps the answer could be positive for large dimensions, but I am not sure.

Comment: To check the model: consider some random walk $X$ starting from the origin $O$ and, for every $x$, some random walk $X^x$ starting from $x$. Assume these are independent and consider their respective ranges $R(X)$ and $R(X^x)$. Then the probability $p$ that none of the new random walks visits the origin is $$p=E\left(\prod_x(1-\mathbf 1_{x\in R(X)}\mathbf 1_{O\in R(X^x)})\right),$$ right?

Comment: Yes this is the model!